# Not using RequestDispatcher to exchange information between Servlet and JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, set

I have a setup such that a popup loads with url ie server.com/getitem?id=2, popup page uses .ready() jquery to call servlet with id from the url. Now, I need to set a bunch of elements on popup page from this servlet. I cannot use RequestDispatcher because it will reload the popup and it'll become an endless load-lookup loop.

I've seen some libraries like this one http://juzuweb.org/javadoc/juzu/Response.Update.html that can set jsp fields from servlet without forwarding. However, I'd like to hear out if there's a simpler way ... this seems to be a simple task but due to the lack of my java web dev experience I'm struggling to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: *"I cannot use RequestDispatcher because it will reload the popup and it'll become an endless load-lookup loop."* This is simply a bug in your code/configuration. Just fix it instead of asking for alternatives/workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a plugin JSTL Core to update elements on JSP page from Servlet. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html